# Purple drywall in bathroom

Tags: bathroom, drywall, shower, mold, moisture

Had some drywallers come to do a kitchen and bathroom today. Is there any reason NOT to use purple moisture resistant board in the bathroom? The drywall has "1/2" high strength LITE - walls and ceiling" printed on it.

Answer (score 4):

No reason not to use them. They are specifically made for humid rooms.

However they are not strong enough for tile walls. For that use concrete (backer boards) that will not flex and ruin your tile work.